# Delete Row Based on Active Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to delete a row's data based on the active cell. I have looked through Google's documentation and I cannot figure out how to do this. I have also searched the forums and found a couple of similar scenarios, but I cannot get it to work. I tried to do this by lopping through an array of data and deleting the row based on the value in the array, but this does not work either. I am sure that I am overcomplicating things here. Here is the code that I have so far...

```
function clearProject() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var sourceArray = source.getRange(1,1,10).getValues();
  var sourceCell = source.getActiveCell();
  var sourceData = sourceCell.getValues();
  //var sourceRow = sourceCell.getRange(sourceCell, );
  var target = ss.getSheetByName('Timeline').getRange(1, 1, 10).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++){
    if(i == sourceData){
      sourceCell.clearContent();
    }
  }
```

Thank you for any help that you can afford!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be as simple as that :

```
function delRowsInActiveRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getActiveRange();
  var height = source.getValues().length;
  var rowPosition = source.getRowIndex();
  ss.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(rowPosition, height);
}
```

This function deletes all the rows that include selected cells.

Comment: this was a much easier solution that I was thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot compare like this `if(i == sourceData)` due to getValues returns

> ...the rectangular grid of values for this range. Returns a
>   two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column. The
>   values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String, depending on
>   the value of the cell. Empty cells will be represented by an empty
>   string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1,
>   the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0].

And I didn't catch your goal, could you plesae add some more explanation?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I still have not completely wrapped my head around arrays, at this point.